# MATLAB simulation runs to infinity, but not when run step by step in debugger

Tags: matlab, loops

My code simulates the shock loading of a rocket upon parachute deployment. When the script is run as a whole the value of the shock goes to infinity. However, when the script is run step by step in the debugger mode it works as intended. I am unsure of what is happening or how to fix it. My code is written as follows:

```
clear all; close all; clc; tic

h_init = 100; %initial altitude, ft
%INPUTS
E = .38e6;      %elastic modulus of nylon, psi
A = (1/16)*(1);  %cross sectional area of cord, in^2
CD = 2.20;       %parachute coefficient of drag
D_p = 144;       %parachute diameter, in
W_p = 2;        %weight of parachute, lbm
W_r = 105;      %dry weight of rocket, lbm
L = 17*3*12;     %length of shock cord, in
v_init = -350;     %initial upwards velocity of rocket/parachute, ft/s
dt = 0.00001;    %simulation time step, s
t_sim = 4;      %total simulation time, s
g = 32.2;       %gravitational acceleration, ft/s^2

%CALCULATIONS
k = (3900)./L;      %spring constant, lbf/in
S_p = pi*D_p.^2/4/144;   %parachute cross sectional area, ft^2
m_p = W_p/g;    %mass of parachute, slugs
m_r = W_r./g;    %mass of rocket, slugs


N = ceil(t_sim/dt);
N_L = length(W_r);

time = dt:dt:t_sim + dt;
Y1 = zeros(N_L,N);
Y2 = zeros(N_L,N);
V1 = zeros(N_L,N);
V2 = zeros(N_L,N);
FS = zeros(N_L,N);
Dr = zeros(N_L,N);
Shock = zeros(N_L,1);
Exten = zeros(N_L,1);
VDiff = zeros(N_L,1);
DrMax = zeros(N_L,1);
TDrop = zeros(N_L,1);

for j = 1:N_L
    v1 = v_init;    %initial velocity of parachute after deployment, ft/s
    y1 = 0;         %initial parachute position relative to deployment altitude, ft
    v2 = v_init;    %initial velocity of rocket after deployment, ft/s
    y2 = 0;         %initial position of rocket relative to deployment altitude, ft

    Y1(j,1) = y1;
    Y2(j,1) = y2;
    V1(j,1) = v1;
    V2(j,1) = v2;
    FS(j,1) = 0;
    Dr(j,1) = 0;
    slack = 1;
    for i = 1:N
        rho = findDensity(h_init+y1);%air density, slug/ft^3
        Q = 144*0.5*rho*v1^2;                           %dynamic pressure, psi
        D = -sign(v1)*(Q/144)*S_p*CD;                   %drag, lbf
        if y1-y2 >= L/12
            delta = 12*(y1-y2)-L;   %shock cord extension, in
            if slack ==1
                TDrop(j) = dt*i;
                slack = 0;
            end
        elseif y2-y1 >= L/12
            delta = -12*(y1-y2)-L;  %shock cord extension, in
        else
            delta = 0;
        end

        fs = k*delta;                                               %spring force, lbf

        F1 = D - W_p - fs;                                          %net force on parachute, lbf
        F2 = fs - W_r(j);                                              %net force on rocket, lbf

        a1 = F1/m_p;                                                %acceleration of parachute, ft/s^2
        a2 = F2/m_r(j);                                                %acceleration of rocket, ft/s^2

        y1 = y1 + v1*dt;                                            %update parachute position, ft
        y2 = y2 + v2*dt;                                            %update rocket position, ft

        v1 = v1 + a1*dt;                                            %update parachute velocity, ft/s
        v2 = v2 + a2*dt;                                            %update rocket velocity, ft/s

        Y1(j,i+1) = y1;
        Y2(j,i+1) = y2;
        V1(j,i+1) = v1;
        V2(j,i+1) = v2;
        FS(j,i+1) = fs;
        Dr(j,i+1) = D;
    end
        Shock(j) = max(FS(j,:));
        Exten(j) = 12*max(Y1(j,:)-Y2(j,:)-L/12);
        VDiff(j) = max(abs(V1(j,:)-V2(j,:)));
        DrMax(j) = max(Dr(j,:));
end

H1 = h_init+Y1;
H2 = h_init+Y2;
fprintf('Max Shock Load: %.2f lbf', Shock)
toc

function density = findDensity(h)
    temp = findTemp(h);
    pressure = findPressure(h);
    density = pressure / (1718 * (temp + 459.7));
end

function pressure = findPressure(h)
    temp = findTemp(h);
    if(h > 82345)
        pressure = 51.97 * (((temp + 459.7) / 389.98) ^ -11.388);
    elseif(h > 36152)
        pressure = 473.1 * exp(1.73 - (0.000048 * h));
    else
        pressure = 2116 * (((temp + 459.7) / 518.6) ^ 5.256);
    end
end

function temp = findTemp(h)
    if(h > 82345)
        temp = (0.00164 * h) - 205.5;
    elseif(h > 36152)
        temp = -70;
    else
        temp = 59 - (0.00356 * h);
    end
end
```

Comment: Which version of MATLAB do you use? It could be an error related to number precision. In old version of MATLAB (e.g. 2010) numerical precision in debugger was lower, so in case of comparison like `y1-y2 >= L/12` the final result could be different in debugger mode.

Comment: I have MATLAB R2017a; the student version. How would running the code in a debugger change the precision of that value?

Comment: In 2017a this problem is fixed. Regarding older version here is an example: `a = 1.00000000001;` `b=1;` the comparison `b>=a` will return true in debug mode and false for standard execution.  Regarding your question I'm not able to run your code because 'atmosphere' is undefined.

Comment: Oh I see. Since the issue is fixed in my version of MATLAB do you have any other ideas of what could be happening. I have heard from friends that MATLAB converts loops to java before running and we think it might be an issue of precision in the converted code, but that is only very slightly better than a wild guess. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Since I can't execute your code my advice is to use 'print debugging', i.e. add some printing into your code and compare outputs.

Comment: What is your expected output? It would be useful to run in the debugger and plot / show the output, vs a plot when not running in the debugger.

Comment: Please, always provide a [mvce]. Your code does not run

Comment: Sorry. I edited the code so that it should run on its own now. I also added a print statement so that you can see that the shock load is going to infinity. An expected output would be anywhere in the range of 1,000 to 3,000 lbf

Comment: Also the easiest way to run the script in debugger is to let it run until the first if statement is satisfied and we go into the code after this line:

    if y1-y2 >= L/12

from here you can go step through each iteration of the for loop until the value of the variable 'fs' stops increasing and starts to decrease. that peak is the maximum load and it should be around 1000 or 2000 lbf. When the script is run like I described above that is what you should get. However if you simply press run then you will get an infinite load for seemingly no reason.

Comment: I have been unable to reproduce "works step by step", because for me it is always `max shock load = inf`.
I put breakpoint in `if slack==1`, because I don't feel like going step by step for 400k steps, when the problems start at 150k. Additionally, profiling it also ends up with shock of inf. As does writing something each line.

I believe you actually don't have the code working step by step, you either simply don't step and go beyond the problematic point at 150k (154539 is the first point when FS starts climbing out of control), or have fewer steps which might not exhibit this behavior.